# PayPal IPN: status "retrying" even though listener is valid

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a non-localhost listener URL.

Using PayPal sandbox.

PayPal IPN history shows a status of "retrying". No HTTP return code.

IPN simulator ALWAYS reports success, even if I use non-listener URL.

Autoreturn disabled.

PDT disabled.

The button HTML:

```
        <form id="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8">

            <input name="cmd" value="_cart" type="hidden">
            <input name="upload" value="1" type="hidden">
            <input name="address_override" value="0" type="hidden">
            <input name="charset" value="utf-8" type="hidden">
            <input name="business" value="xxxxx-facilitator@freenet.de" type="hidden">
            <input name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/?babor=ipn_verify" type="hidden">
            <input name="return" value="http://example.com/danke-fur-ihren-einkauf" type="hidden">
            <input name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/" type="hidden">
            <input id="item_name_1" name="item_name_1" value="" type="hidden">
            <input id="item_number_1" name="item_number_1" value="" type="hidden">
            <input id="amount_1" name="amount_1" value="" type="hidden">
            <input name="currency_code" value="EUR" type="hidden">
            <input id="email" name="email" value="" type="hidden">
            <input id="no_shipping" name="no_shipping" value="0" type="hidden">
            <input name="country" value="DE" type="hidden">

            <input name="rm" value="2" type="hidden">

            <input name="amount_1" value="10" type="hidden">
            <input name="item_quantity_1" value="1" type="hidden">
            <input name="item_name_1" value="Gutschein" type="hidden">

            <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/pp_cc_mark_37x23.jpg"><button type="submit" id="payment_button">Buy Now</button>

        </form>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The URL can be valid, sure, but there must be some sort of an error happening with your script that is causing it to send a 500 response back to PayPal instead of a 200.  This will cause it to retry.

Follow the steps outlined in this article on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you'll be able to find the issue.